# Confusion with dummy indices and the notation of tensor contraction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensors

Consider a differential manifold M on which there exists a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. On M, there is an infinite number of tangent spaces for each point $p \in M$. Given this fact there exists Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$ which introduce the connection, which is just a connection of tangent spaces on the manifold M.  The metric connection is given by $$\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}=\frac12g^{\lambda\sigma}\left(\partial_{\nu}g_{\sigma\mu}+\partial_{\mu}g_{\sigma\nu}-\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu\nu}\right).$$ Its obvious that $\sigma$ is our dummy index and is being summed over; however, upon looking at a proof of the covariant derivative of the metric tensor being zero, I saw the term $$\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\beta}\delta^{\sigma}_{\sigma}=\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\beta}.$$ Why is the result of that contraction the Christoffel symbol itself? Did the sigma in the contravariant index of the Christoffel symbol contract with the covariant index of the Kronecker delta or was is because that by definition the Kronecker delta symbol goes to 1? Which operation happened?

Comment: The second line doesn't look like sensible index notation to me. A typo, perhaps?

Comment: $\Gamma_{\mu\beta}^\sigma \delta_\sigma^\sigma$ violates Einstein's convention because $\sigma$ appears twice above. It should probably read something like $\Gamma_{\mu\beta}^\alpha \delta_\alpha^\sigma = \Gamma_{\mu\beta}^\sigma$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thats what figured. Since the $\alpha$ index appears in the upper index and the lower index, it sums out, i.e it contracts. So for example if we have some tensor $T^{\alpha\nu}R_{\alpha\mu}$,  can we write one of the tensors as a mixed tensor, i.e when do we cancel the index and not write out the sum?

Comment: $T^{\alpha\nu}R_{\alpha\mu}$ is just that, a sum. You can only contract things when you have a Kronecker delta, or raise/lower indices when you have a metric tensor. So things like $g^{\alpha \nu}R_{\alpha\mu} = R^\nu_{~\mu}$ and $T^{\alpha\nu}g_{\alpha\mu} = T_\mu^{~\nu}$ make sense.

Comment: Ok thanks, I knew that it looked like raising and lowering with the metric just didn't know the same could be applied to the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Yes, the Kronecker delta's action is essentially doing an index subtitution,

Comment: $g^{jl}=g^{jk}\delta^l_k=\delta^{jl}$